# Magento checkout cart doesn't show right numbers in explore

Tags: magento, internet-explorer, checkout

I have a problem with the checkout page in internet explore. If I add a product to the cart it works well. Only when I click on continue shopping, shows the cart in the header items: 0 If I add a product to the cart I have 2 products in my cart, but when I click on continue shopping or any other page displays the shopping cart in the header items: 1 but this should be 2. I also can not remove products from the shopping cart with the icon. I have fcp already disabled and cookies set to 86400, but the problem remains. Also, no error messages in the log. In other browsers I do not have this problem. Our website http://www.origineelkadootje.com

Answer (score 0):

The chat is throwing an error:

```
SyntaxError: unterminated string literal
$zopim.livechat.window.setTheme('</body>.
```

Fix  or disable this module. It's probably stopping/blocking the required javascript execution needed to update the cart.